# How to restrict the view selection on the default list page SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a SharePoint Online intranet portal where everyone is having Read access. However I have few lists where certain records should be viewed by admins only.
Is there a way to restrict a view to certain Group on SP Online. or any other approach? Ido not want to create folders inside list and break role inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

For SPO modern sites, item unique permission will be the best and only approach. You can set a special view to hide columns but not items. Manage the access of these important records to only allow certain admins.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You can consider making a custom permission level that restricts view creation and then pre-create views for the readers and have your admins create personal views.

Note that this is not a watertight solution as your readers can technically see the items and retrieve them for example using the Rest API